# Error serializing javafx.Color with Gson lib

Tags: java, javafx, gson

i'm creating a program where i need to write an array of Pixel(x, y, Color)(Where x and y are int) in a Json file with the Gson library; (Im using Intellij on Arch)

This is what i did to add "Pixel" in the list:

```
List <Pixel> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Pixel(1,1,Color.TRANSPARENT));
        list.add(new Pixel(1, 2, Color.BEIGE));
        list.add(new Pixel(2, 1, Color.RED));
```

Then i wrote them in the json file with:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("pixel.json");
fWriter.write(gson.toJson(list));
```

When i start the program i had these errors:

Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonIOException: Failed making field 'javafx.scene.paint.Color#red' accessible; either increase its visibility or write a custom TypeAdapter for its declaring type.

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final float javafx.scene.paint.Color.red accessible: module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.scene.paint" to module com.google.gson

So i add in module-info.java:

`opens javafx.scene.paint to com.google.gson;`

But then i had this problem:

```
warning: package is empty or does not exist: javafx.scene.paint
    opens javafx.scene.paint to com.google.gson;
```

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to serialize some other representation of the color, e.g. rgba values or a web string.

Comment: You can't `opens` a package that is not in your own module via the `module-info` descriptor. You'd have to use an `--add-opens` JVM argument. But the better solution is to customize the (de)serialization, as [demonstrated by James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76094273/6395627).

Answer (score 3):

Not tested, but try creating custom [de]serializers for `Color`:

```
public class ColorSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Color> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Color color, Type colorType, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("red", color.getRed());
        json.addProperty("green", color.getGreen());
        json.addProperty("blue", color.getBlue());
        json.addProperty("opacity", color.getOpacity());
        return json;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ColorDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Color> {

    @Override
    public Color deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        JsonObject json = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        double red = json.get("red").getAsDouble();
        double green = json.get("green").getAsDouble();
        double blue = json.get("blue").getAsDouble();
        double opacity = json.get("opacity").getAsDouble();
        return Color.color(red, green, blue, opacity);
    }
}
```

Then of course just do

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Color.class, new ColorSerializer())
    .setPrettyPrinting()
    .create();
FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("pixel.json");
fWriter.write(gson.toJson(list));
```

And to read it back in, register a `ColorDeserializer`.