# A problem about using both of gson and javafx.beans.property

Tags: javafx

I have a Object bounds controls.

```
public class Record {
    private final SimpleStringProperty uid = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty person = new SimpleStringProperty();
    //getters and setters
```

Then, i use com.google.gson to deserialize: *new Gson().fromJson(lineStr, Record.class);*
It takes a reflect exception:`Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty.bean accessible: module javafx.base does not "opens javafx.beans.property" to module com.google.gson`
In module-info.java:

```
module myModule {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.base;
    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    
    opens myModule  to javafx.fxml,com.google.gson;

    exports ......
}
```

I tried to add `opens javafx.beans.property to com.google.gson;`, the IDE shows `Package not found: javafx.beans.property`.
I don't know much about javafx.beans module's dependency relations.I guess the correct solution is to open the javafx.beans.property to gson.Who can help me :) ?

Comment: Opening the `javafx.base` module to Gson is not the proper solution. The proper solution is to configure Gson to somehow ignore the JavaFX property objects and just deal with the **values** of the JavaFX properties. I'm not greatly familiar with Gson, but there might be a way to tell Gson to use getters/setters instead of field access. Or you can create a custom serializer/deserializer for your model class. Or you can create a DTO-like class specifically for (de)serializing with Gson.

Comment: I don't believe GSON supports "property access" (i.e. using `getX()` and `setX()` methods, instead of directly accessing the fields), which (very much my opinion) betrays a misunderstanding of encapsulation on the part of the library designers. If you can switch to Jackson for your JSON [de]serialization, you can configure it to use the property accessor methods, which will solve the problem. If you are stuck with GSON, the cleanest solution is probably to define custom [de]serializers for your `Record` class. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/76091092/ for something similar.

Comment: Another option is to write [de]serializers for all the JavaFX property types, and register those. That's quite a bit of work, but fortunately someone [already seems to have done this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794500/serialize-javafx-model-with-gson?rq=2).

Comment: Thank you all!I wrote a deserializer to solve it, it seems simple and effective, even if not elegant. : )